# how to run terasort with flink?

Tags: apache-flink, terasort, bigdata

i just configure my flink cluster (1.0.3 version) and i whanted to run tersort with the flink framework, but its me returned the next erreor, i used this comamnde to run my programm:

```
/bin/flink run -c --class es.udc.gac.flinkbench.ScalaTeraSort flinkbench-assembly-1.0.jar hdfs://192.168.3.89:8020/teragen/10mo hdfs://192.168.3.89:8020/teragen/rstflink
```

and its me return this :

```
Cluster configuration: Standalone cluster with JobManager at localhost/127.0.0.1:6123
Using address localhost:6123 to connect to JobManager.
JobManager web interface address http://localhost:8081
Starting execution of program
2017-06-23 10:28:43,692 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat         - Total input paths to process : 2
Spent 2278ms computing base-splits.
Spent 2ms computing TeraScheduler splits.
Computing input splits took 2281ms
Sampling 2 splits of 2
Making -1 from 100000 sampled records

------------------------------------------------------------
 The program finished with the following exception:

org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error.
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:545)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:419)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:339)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:831)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:256)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1073)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend$2.call(CliFrontend.java:1120)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend$2.call(CliFrontend.java:1117)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext$1.run(HadoopSecurityContext.java:43)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1656)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:40)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1116)
Caused by: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at es.udc.gac.flinkbench.terasort.TeraInputFormat$TextSampler.createPartitions(TeraInputFormat.java:103)
    at es.udc.gac.flinkbench.terasort.TeraInputFormat.writePartitionFile(TeraInputFormat.java:183)
    at es.udc.gac.flinkbench.ScalaTeraSort$.main(ScalaTeraSort.scala:49)
    at es.udc.gac.flinkbench.ScalaTeraSort.main(ScalaTeraSort.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:528)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: The error seems not to be Flink related because the exception occurs in "es.udc.gac.flinkbench.terasort.TeraInputFormat". Maybe you can post some more code or a link to the code base.

Comment: thank you @twalthr, i use a jar file in examples of flink, please if you have an code to terasort programme with flink can you give me it

Comment: I found this Github repo: https://github.com/eastcirclek/terasort
Have you tried that?

Comment: Here is the corresponding talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_exWHj1vmo

Comment: @twalthr yes i tried with this code ( github.com/eastcirclek/terasort) but its me return the erreor : ava.lang.NoSuchFieldError: tupleType at eastcircle.terasort.FlinkTeraSort$$anon$7.protected$tupleType(FlinkTeraSort.scala:57) at eastcircle.terasort.FlinkTeraSort$$anon$7$$anon$4.